# what is the method to change or fetch specific row values onto the form using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a form and table on a jsp page, for example,

```
<form id="myForm">
    <tr><td><label for="first_name">First Name</label></td>
    <td><select id="first-name">
        <option value="1">Arun</option>
        <option value="2">Ganesh</option>
        <option value="3">Suresh</option>
        <option value="4">Sanganabasu</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></td>
    <td><select id="last-name">
        <option value="1">Hulagabal</option>
        <option value="2">Cheemalamudi</option>
        <option value="3">Ganiger</option>
        <option value="4">Kattriguppe</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label for="email">Email</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="button" id="row" value="Add" ></td></tr>
    </form>
```

All this code is on same jsp page, when ever i submit form, rows are added into the table "list".
i.e., When i click add a row is generated dynamically on a table,

```
<table id="list">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>First Name</th>
           <th>last name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Password</th>
           <th>&nbsp;</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td><a href="">Edit</a></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

but when i click on edit link on a dynamically generated table, i need to fetch those specific row values, on to the form "myForm". i have done in the following way for edit row function,

```
//Edit row function for fetching specific row values on to the form
$("td", this).on("click", function () {
            var tds = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
            $.each(tds, function (i, v) {
                $($("#myForm input")[i]).val($(v).text());
            });
        });
```

But this is not loading specific row values on to the form and not updating. 
Is this the correct way? Or i have to make any changes?
Can anyone help me to solve the problem....

Comment: For future reference, Java and JavaScript are two totally different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#list').on('click', 'td:last-child', function (e) {
    var $ins = $('#first-name, #last-name, #email, #password');
    $(this).siblings().each(function (i) {
        $ins.eq(i).val($(this).text().trim())
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.. @ Arun P Johny. But it is not fetching the values. Is there any other way to retrieve specific row values...?

Comment: Thank you soo much..@Arun P Johny.  Now i am able to fetch values on to form. I have many fields with some calculation part in the form. And i have to display only the total amount on the table. As i don't have all fields to be displayed on table, but when i click edit the other fields which are not on the table should also be fetched on to the form... How can i fetch them...

Comment: Please Can you check this fiddle.... http://jsfiddle.net/ca078/runsn84r/2/ And help me to solve problem.. @Arun P Johny.